# Display when no results found on keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple classes called `post-content` on `div` and have a search box, who's event is fired on `keyup`. If there's no matching result, I'd like to display '*No results match*'

```
$('.post-content').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-search-term', $(this).text().toLowerCase());
});
$('#search-criteria').on('keyup', function() {
  var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('.post-content').each(function() {
    if ($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

I tried creating the element inside the else block, but it seems to fire everytime the key is pressed, thus printing the entire page with the event.

Comment: Can we have a fiddle or something executable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler way.

Hide all then show the relevant posts.

```js
$('.post-content').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-search-term', $(this).text().toLowerCase());
});

$('#search-criteria').on('keyup', function() {

  var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('.post-content').hide();

  if (searchTerm) {
    var matches = $('.post-content').filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']');
    $('.no-match').toggle(matches.length == 0)
    matches.show();
  }
});
```

```css
.no-match {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search-criteria" />

<div class=post-content>aaaaaaaa</div>
<div class=post-content>bbbbbbbb</div>
<div class=post-content>aaaaaaaa</div>
<div class=post-content>bbbbbbbb</div>
<div class=post-content>aaaaaaaa</div>
<div class=post-content>bbbbbbbb</div>
<div class="no-match">No Matches</div>
```

Comment: Hello there, I tried your implementation, the snippet you presented seem to work just fine. I am indeed grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not show and hide the no-result element instead of creating it dynamically?

```
$('#search-criteria').on('keyup', function() {

  var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  var term_found = false;

  $('.post-content').each(function() {
    if ($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0) {

      $(this).show();
      term_found = true;

    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

  // show if not found, hide if found
  $('#post-content-no-result').toggle(!term_found);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.post-content').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-search-term', $(this).text().toLowerCase());
});
$('#search-criteria').change(function() {
  var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('.post-content').each(function() {
    if ($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0) {
      $(this).show();
      $(this).parent().find(".noresult").remove();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
      $(this).parent().append( "<div class='noresult'>Test</div>" );
    }
  });
});
```

I guess you need sth like that. Create div with `.noresult` class and content you need to have.

Comment: I don't think this would work as .noresult can be hidden or shown multiple times and probably it will be shown if the last element in .each function doesn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: What is the point of this if then. If there is a result, xxx.length is supposed to be >0, right?

Comment: Yes The length will be greater than 0 but you are missing out something which can be seen if you observe minutely. Let's say .post-content contains multiple items (10 items). The first three satisfy the condition, hence they will go to if condition and execute accordingly but the latter seven which do not satisy the condition will make the else block execute and the .noresult block will become visible eventually.

Comment: You right. Depends then how many post-content are we filtering. If its one, it will work :P More might be a problem.

Comment: I modified according to your tip :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a flag to check if results are found are not.

```
$('.post-content').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-search-term', $(this).text().toLowerCase());
});
$('#search-criteria').on('keyup', function() {
  var isResultFound = false;
  var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('.post-content').each(function() {
    if ($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0) {
      isResultFound = true;
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }

if(!isResultFound) {
    $('#noResultDiv').show();
} else {
    $('#noResultDiv').hide();
}
  });
});
```